Couldnt connect to SAP HANA via JDBC using apache dbcp2(connection pool)
I am trying to connect to SAP HANA cloud database. But getting error like

java.sql.SQLException: Error preloading the connection pool
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:573)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:734)
at sql.SAPHanaConnPool.main(SAPHanaConnPool.java:90)
Caused by: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: Cannot connect to jdbc:sap://d47b79f4-9ee5-4f27-b1ed-a34f1206a004.hana.trial-us10.hanacloud.ondemand.com:443/ [Object is closed: com.sap.db.jdbc.SecureChannelSession@33308786 <sap_host>:443 ConnectionID:0 SessionID:0 on sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl ConnectionID:0 SessionID:0].
at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:126)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:222)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:50)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB._connect(DriverSapDB.java:3483)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB.connect(DriverSapDB.java:3056)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:571)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:212)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:569)
... 2 more

I tried using simple JDBC without using connection pool. I am able to connect to SAP HANA. But with connection getting object is closed error
